# Microsoft FIM vs AD

Tags: authentication, ldap, identity, openldap

what is the difference between Microsoft FIM and AD authentication.What does it additionally provide.is FIM based on LDAP.what are the alternatives for FIM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FIM is An ForeFront Identity management (FIM) system is a framework for business processes that facilitates the management of electronic identities. The framework includes the technology needed to support identity management.

FIM technology can be used to initiate, capture, record and manage user identities and their related access permissions in an automated fashion. This ensures that access privileges are granted according to one interpretation of policy and all individuals and services are properly authenticated, authorized and audited.

FIM Provide

1.User Management 
    1.store users in application database
    2.Simple Identity data: Display name,telephone number,email
    3.Administrative data:employee Id ,manager,start/end date,objectSID
    4.System Data:creator,created time,resource ID.resource type
    5.Search Capabilities

2.group Management
    1.Three types of memebership
        1.manual
        2.manager-Based
        3.criteria-based
    2.Automatically Updated (when group member changes)
    3.Easy to integrate with Active Directory
        1.Distribution and security 
        2.Domain local,global and Universal
        3.can be email enable
    4.Extensible to support other data sources
    5.Owership
        1. can be use for permission
        2.approval of membership additions

3.credentials management
    1.Certificate Management(FIM -CMS)
    2.self-service password reset
    3.Password Synchronization

4.policy management
     1.Can be implemented through Management policy rules(MPRs)
     2.Powerful  and  flexible

There is no relation between AD authentication and FIM.

Using AD Authentication you can authorize user to access different resources in distributed network.
Eg.ADFS -Active Directory Federal Services

Comment: can I integrate it with any openLDAP based Directory services(from now refered as system X). for example if the FIM has a set of users can I import these users to X and if i make any changes to FIM then the change should reflect in system X also.

Comment: can you also suggest alternative to FIM. or similar softwares

Comment: you can google for IAM Vendors and you can find lots of Application & YES you can integrateFIM  with any other system like LDIF,lotus note, SQL server,Oracle database,IBM Directory Server,ADLDS,Delimited text file......